# Menu Resource Item Position Title to Left of Icon

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to position the title text for a menu item to the left of the icon rather than to the right in an ActionBar?  So in:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:title="Begin"
    android:icon="@drawable/ForwardArrow"
    android:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

It would appear "Begin ->" instead of "-> Begin"

Comment: I don't think so, but you can always use `android:actionLayout` and create your own `View` that looks the way you want.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  If you post that as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can define things like `android:actionButtonStyle` in a theme and apply that to your activity, I am not aware that you can use that to turn around and affect the positioning of the image versus the text.

However, you can use `android:actionLayout` in your `<item>` element to replace the stock action button with something else of your own design. If you putter around the Android source and find where these action buttons come from, I suspect that you will find that they are styled `Button` objects using the compound drawable stuff to put an image alongside the text caption. Cloning that and switching the side for the image, then using that for your `actionLayout`, should work, at least in theory.