# Can we have an icon on right side of text in menu item in android?

Tags: android, layout, menu, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have a requirement to have text and image icon in menu item, with icon on right side of text. I am able to get icon on to left of text but want it on right side. Please help me out.

This is my menu.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuNavigate" android:icon="@drawable/menuicon" android:showAsAction="always" android:title="@string/menu" android:orderInCategory="9" >       
        <menu>                      
            <item android:id="@+id/Menu_Home" android:title="@string/menu_home" android:icon="@drawable/rtarrow_r" android:showAsAction="withText"/>                        
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want to have arrow on right most side..

Please help me out

Comment: refer commonsware's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368260/menu-resource-item-position-title-to-left-of-icon

Comment: Image is not visible.Edit your question with the image?

Comment: @Manishika: I am unable to add image to the question, as i am very new to stack overflow

Comment: @Shruti: Its the reverse case with me as i have the items in sub menu - (Title ->), where -> is icon. Thanks in advance

Comment: ![Description of Image][1]

 [1]: "paste your image path" eg.http://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg

Comment: @Manishika: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJjk.png  - Image path

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setActionView` to attribute acustom layout to your menu item.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29).